# как задать условие a or b not in c

Tags: python, if

есть ли возможность такого в python. Есть ли возможность уложить это в один if, чтобы не писать

```
if a not in c:
    if b not in c:
```

спасибо!

Comment: `a not in c or b not in c`

Comment: ок, а not in c так работает?

Comment: работает. исправил

Comment: @eri спасибо болшое!

Comment: if 'Sponsored' not in text or 'Ad' not in text:
     hotels[text] = link     все равно появляется ключ со словом Sponsored... что я не так пишу? если оставляю только if "Sponsored" not in text, то ключа нет((

Comment: @eri Это не такое условие. Тут нужно and, а не or.

Comment: @Эникейщик пока я писал ответ условия задачи поменялись 3-4 раза)

Answer (score 4):

Вот так :

`a not in c and b not in c`